# Passing additional data in a ViewBag to the EditorTemplate from the Partial

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views, viewbag

I have a partial view:

```
@ModelType ProjectCreateViewModel
@Code 
    Dim vdd = New ViewDataDictionary()
    vdd.Add("Classes", "template")
End Code
@Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.Project.InvoiceScheduleBasedOnDates, vdd))
```

In this partial view I create new ViewDataDictionary to pass additional data to my editor. In the editor I access ViewBag.Classes and its value is null. However, when I debug I can see that the ViewBag contains "Classes" key. Here a screen dump:

[image: You can see that var1 is null, but ViewBag contains "Classes"]

Why is this happening to me and what can I do to pass this value from a partial to editor template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass it as an anonymous object:

```
@ModelType ProjectCreateViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.Project.InvoiceScheduleBasedOnDates, New With { .Classes = "template" })
```

and in your template:

```
@Modelype InvoiceDate
@Code
    Dim var1 = ViewBag.Classes
    ...
End Code
```

Comment: Yep, that works. What was I doing wrong? Is it possible to access the data the way I did? Question just as an exercise.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MichalB., the `additionalViewData` parameter that you are passing to the `EditorFor` helper is of type `Object`. When you pass an anonymous object, its properties are automatically injected into the view data of the template as keys. In your case you have passed an object of type `ViewDataDictionary` so inside your template you can access its properties using for example `ViewBag.Keys` and `ViewBag.Values`.